# How to get a single record in a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `fixtures` that contains this structure:

```
id | comp_id  | round_id | 
 1     10         11          
 2     10         12         
 3     10         11
```

I want get all the result only for one "round_id", so the final result should be: 1, 3 or 2

I made this query:

```
SELECT *
 from fixtures f 
  LEFT 
  JOIN rounds r 
    ON r.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM rounds WHERE id = f.round_id)
WHERE comp_id = 10
```

but this will return all the fixtures records available, I need to return just the fixtures for a single round which I don't know the number.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rounds` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `round_id` INT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: rounds table ???

Comment: I mean could you share the structure of `rounds` table, also ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So, how would you like to determine which one?

Comment: @GolezTrol for example using MIN as I tried in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only that fixtures, that have the minimum round ID **used in `fixtures`** (not the minimum `id` from `rounds`, as this might not be used in `fixtures`!).

```
SELECT *
       FROM fixtures f
       WHERE f.round_id = (SELECT min(ff.round_id)
                                  FROM fixtures ff);
```

If you also want round data in it (I cannot tell if you have a join in your query because you wanted the round data or if this is just due to your attempts to filter), you can join `rounds`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM fixtures f
            INNER JOIN rounds r
                       ON r.id = f.round_id
       WHERE f.round_id = (SELECT min(ff.round_id)
                                  FROM fixtures ff);
```

Of course `min()` can be replaced with some other suitable function (like e.g. `max()`) or you can come up with a completely other idea how to get one single `round_id` from `fixtures` to use. The important thing is, it must be exactly one ID and it must be used in `fixtures`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one record and you don't really care which, append LIMIT 1 to the end of the query.

Comment: I mean, I need to return only the fixtures of a single round not return one row..

Answer (score 0):

try using group statement

```
  SELECT *
 from fixtures f 
  LEFT 
  JOIN rounds r 
    ON r.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM rounds WHERE id = f.round_id)
WHERE comp_id = 10
GROUP BY r.round_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> so the final result should be: 1, 3 or 2

Applying an `order by` clause will fetch you the result in that manner:

```
Select id from fixtures f
where f.round_id 
order by round_id asc;
```

> return just the fixtures for a single round

Give that `where` clause a equality condition to fetch a single round
Example:

```
Select id from fixtures f
where f.round_id = 11
order by round_id asc;
```

^ Returns a column of 'id' and rows 1 and 3, which are associated to round_id 11.

Comment: the problem's that I don't know the number of round_id, that's why I just need to return a single round_id from fixtures

Comment: How about `where f.round_id IN (Select min(id) from rounds)` ?

Comment: this will return empty result

Comment: I tried it myself on workbench and it does return ids 1 & 3 for the minimum round_id, which is 11. I presumed that round_id in your fixtures table maps to the primary key id values in your rounds table. Isn't this correct?

Comment: yes, round_id is the FK of rounds table (id)